# Polynomial of $11^{th}$ degree

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $11$ such that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$,for $x=0,1,2,3.......,11$.
Then what is the value of $f(12)?$

My attempt at this is:
Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+......+a_{11}x^{11}$

$f(0)=\frac{1}{0+1}=1=a_0$

$f(1)=\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+......+a_{11} $

$f(2)=\frac{1}{2+1}=\frac{1}{3}=a_0+2a_1+4a_2+8a_3+......+2^{11}a_{11} $
.
.
.
$f(11)=\frac{1}{11+1}=\frac{1}{12}=a_0+11a_1+11^2a_2+11^3a_3+......+11^{11}a_{11} $

for calculating $f(12)$, I need to calculate $a_0,a_1,a_2,....,a_11$ but I could solve further.Is my approach right,how can I solve further or there is another right way to solve it.

$(A)\frac{1}{13}$ 
 $(B)\frac{1}{12}$
 $(C)0 $

$(D)\frac{1}{7}$

which one is correct answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

Let $(x+1)f(x)=1+A\prod_{r=0}^{11}(x-r)$ where $A$ is an arbitrary constant

Comment: A is not an arbitrary constant. It is a fixed constant whose value we happen not to know.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, See any arbitrary finite constant will satisfy the given condition, right?

Comment: But f is a fixed, given polynomial. Your equation can only hold for exactly one scalar A.

Comment: Solving for $f(x)$ from your equation will in general yield a *rational function* - there is a unique choice of $A$ for which it simplifies to a polynomial. Can you find that value for $A$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I was pointing to the given condition. But, from that  $A$ can assume any arbitrary finite scalar value, right?

Comment: @anon, What's that unique choice?

Comment: Hint: The RHS is divisible by $x+1\iff $ RHS $=0$ when $x=-1$. :-)

Comment: what should be the f(12), 0 or 1/12?

Comment: I think I get it, we need 1+x to divide the RHS, We can do that by evaluating the A*product term with x=-1 and then figuring out what value A needs to be so the RHS vanishes, I make that A=-1/12! . Now, finale, f(12) would be 0 - choice C.  Any confirmation ? Good one!

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat less vague...

$(x+1)f(x)-1$ is a polynomial of degree 12 with roots at every integer in $[0,11]$, so could be $$(x+1)f(x)-1 = A \prod_{c=0}^{11} x-c$$
for some/any (nonzero) constant $A$.

When $x=-1$, we have $(0)f(-1)-1 = A (-1)^{12} 12!$, or $-1 = A \, 12!$ and discover only $A = \frac{-1}{12!}$ is consistent with the givens.  (Why $-1$?  Because it is the only choice we haven't already used (we have used the integers 0, ... 11) that makes some expression containing $x$s zero.)

Hence, $13 f(12) - 1 = \frac{-1}{12!} 12!$ and $f(12) = \frac{-1+1}{13} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let us shift the variable: $g(y)=\dfrac1y$ for $y=1,2,\cdots12$.

Then $$\frac{A(y-1)(y-2)\cdots(y-12)+1}y$$ is a polynomial of degree $11$ and coincides with $\dfrac1y$ at the given points, provided that the numerator has no independent term, i.e. $12!A+1=0$.

From this,

$$f(12)=g(13)=\frac{A(13-1)(13-2)\cdots(13-12)+1}{13}=\frac{12!A+1}{13}=0.$$