# Polynomial of degree 2015 is equal to $1/x$ for $x=1,2,...,2016$

Tags: polynomials

Degree of $W(x)$ is 2015. $W(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x=1,2,...,2016$.
Calculate $W(2017)$.

I think that $W(2017)=0$ but how to prove this?
I thought of $W(x)=\frac{1-(x-1)(x-2)...(x-2016)}{x}$, but I don't know how to factor $x$ out of counter.

Comment: I do not think the $W$ that you defined is a polynomial.

Comment: Consider $xW(x)-1$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: That relation holds only for a particular set of $x$, not all $x$.

Comment: Same type of problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374128/polynomial-of-11th-degree?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434237/the-degree-of-the-polynomial-wx-is-equal-2015-knowing-that-wn?rq=1).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1379483/42969

Comment: Using my "hopefully induction" I say that $W(2017)=0$ :))

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the leading coefficient of $W(x)$ is $1$. Note that the degree of $W(x)$ is $2015$ and so the degree of $xW(x)-1$ is $2016$. Now $xW(x)-1$ has roots $1,2,\cdots,2016$. Then
$$ xW(x)-1\equiv (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2016). $$
So
$$ 2017W(2017)-1=2016\cdot2015\cdot\cdots1=2016! $$
and hence
$$ W(2017)=\frac{2016!+1}{2017}. $$

Comment: The leading coefficient of $W(x)$ is not $1$.